# How to add i2c LTC2944 battery gauge in OpenWrt

Tags: drivers, openwrt

I am planning to use LTC2944 on my Allwinner A20 board that has openwrt based OS.

The chip is detected when I run i2c-detect -y 2 and prints the address 64 0b01100100 as per the data sheet

[image]

using i2cdetect -y 2 I can get it on address 64

[image]

How can load the driver for it in A20. I saw a patch writen for rpi * [950-0289-overlays-Add-ltc294x-battery](https://frickel.cloud/firmware/openwrt/-/blob/79e639160048e9cfcc6d91b0a537840cdd4b72ac/target/linux/brcm2708/patches-4.14/950-0289-overlays-Add-ltc294x-battery-gauge.patch)... 1

Can some one guide me what are the steps to follow in order make it work in Allwinner A20.

Comment: Just make sure your device tree is correct - see [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/power/supply/ltc2941.txt) ... (?)

Comment: @MurrayJensen Thanks for your quick response. I am not well fimiliar with this. Do you mean I should make sure if the dts of my board contains this block. Otherwise add it and rebuild the complete image. Correct?

Comment: the device tree is usually loaded by the boot loader and passed to the kernel at boot time (addr in a register I think?) - the kernel will use the information in it to load device drivers and configure devices - the doc I linked to gives an example entry in the device tree source for the LTC2943 on a Topic Miami Florida board - your device tree should have something similar for your LTC2944 - your device tree is likely to be built at the same time as the kernel and probably bundled in a single image (not familiar with the Allwinner A20) so yes, make sure your dts has the entry, if not rebuild.